# FedRamp Moderate question about hashing MD5

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash, md5, fedramp

If I use MD5 but not for cryptography purposes, and not for any authentication or authorization mechanism, Am I in violation of FedRamp Moderate?

Comment: What exactly are you using MD5 for?

Comment: Let say that it's a bad use of md5 and likely could had been used other techniques. But that is the way it is. In this case the code is just getting the MD5 of an image in some way.That image is not user provided and user have  never access to the images.So it is not used for security in any way and the origin is trusted as it is internal to the application